# Minimum sample size for time series cross-validation (tsCV)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cross-validation

I am doing cross-validation of an autoregressive neural network model and I am using the `tsCV` function (`forecast` package) proposed by Hyndman (2014) and illustrated [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/).

The problem: it's necessary for the CV to require an initial minimum sample, and the `tsCV` function has the argument `initial`. On the other hand, Hyndman points out that "you do not even have to specify the minimum sample size for model fitting, as it will silently fit models beginning with a single observation, and return to missing value whenever the model can not be estimated."

In the book, there is an example arbitrarily using the initial sample as k = 48. I looked for some questions answered by the author on his profile [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=2), but I did not find it.

How could I decide the minimum sample size for this kind of CV?

HYNDMAN, R. J. Forecasting: Principles & Practice.2014